# Alternate to IFNA for my INDEX MATCH formula

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, google-sheets-formula

Pretty new to this level of formula and coding, and am learning on the go. I recently got some help to make an INDEX MATCH formula work with an IFNA statement. It works perfectly now (Link below, "Session 1" Sheet, Cells E14-E23)

I tried to use the same style of formula in E29-E38 (highlighted in orange). However due to requiring multiple IF statements, the IFNA isn't allowing it to work now.

I need to search and match what is in cells D29-38 of "Session 1" sheet to where it is listed in column A of varying other sheets (you can see which sheets in the code in E29-E38) and then bring me back the value in Column B of those sheets for the matched column A item.

I have the formula I tried to adapt below:

=iferror(ifna(IF($B29="Set",INDEX('Set DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D29,'Set DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),na()),if($B29="Vol",INDEX('Vol DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D29,'Vol DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),na()),if($B29="EXTVol",INDEX('EXTVol DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D29,'EXTVol DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),na()),if($B29="EXTVol2",INDEX('EXTVol2 DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D29,'EXTVol2 DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),na()),if($A29="DMT",INDEX('DMT DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D29,'DMT DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),"")),"")

And also a link to a copied version of the sheet for reference:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pkN3tKTFhFweDdKfQ3SZDnA_gqqF-B5rso1zc1v3TZY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for anyone who is able to help with this !

Elliot

Comment: Have you tried using VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP? @ElliotStratton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have an answer that works for you.
Try this formula in E29, and drag it down:

```
=IF($B29="Set",           ifna(INDEX('Set DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,     match($D29,'Set DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),    "Skip1"),
   if($B29="Vol",         ifna(INDEX('Vol DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,     match($D29,'Vol DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),    "Skip2"),
     if($B29="EXTVol",    ifna(INDEX('EXTVol DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,  match($D29,'EXTVol DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)), "Skip3"),
       if($B29="EXTVol2", ifna(INDEX('EXTVol2 DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B, match($D29,'EXTVol2 DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),"Skip4"),
         if($A29="DMT",   ifna(INDEX('DMT DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,     match($D29,'DMT DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0)),    "Skip5"),
           "Skip6")))))
```

I just shuffled the formula you had there, and after a bit, it seemed to work out.  You may want to review the `IFERROR` or `IFNA` statements that you want as part of that.  You had `NA()` Where I have `"Skip x"`, which helped me figure out what was happening.

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps! That worked spot on, I hadn't ever thought to put the "SKIPs" in to be able to see where the errors are occurring! Thanks for that !

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding here, but it seems that your entries in B29:B38 can be used to create all sheet names to be referenced. So if you put the following in E29 and dragged it down to D38, it should provide what you're looking for:

```
=IF(A29="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D29,INDIRECT("'"&B29&" DD Skill by Skill'!A3:B"),2,FALSE),"No "&B29&" Sheet"))
```

You'll notice that my IFERROR is set up to tell you if the sheets preface named in B29:B38 is not an existing sheet (as is the case at the time of my writing this with Row 33: "Pass2").